# why a higher mysql version give errors

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql query which run normally in local host but when i upload it to the real server where a higher version of MySQL is installed it give me error:

```
" #1054 - Unknown column 'subject.customers_fullname' in 'field list' "
```

Here is the query ...

```
SELECT nf.*,
       actor.customers_fullname AS actor_name,
       actor.customers_id AS actor_id,
       subject.customers_fullname AS subject_name
FROM portal_notifications nf,
     customers actor,
     customers SUBJECT
WHERE subject_id = 1
  AND nf.actor_id = actor.customers_id
  AND nf.subject_id = SUBJECT.customers_id
  AND status = 'unseen'
ORDER BY nf.id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Did you check that subject.customers_fullname exists in the customers table on the server? Also, not sure if MySQL is case-sensitive on aliases so you might need SUBJECT.customers_fullname so that it matches the alias case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write this in field list because alisas name is `SUBJECT` and you are used `subject` which is case sensitive in `UNIX`.

```
SUBJECT.customers_fullname AS subject_name
```

Instead Of

```
subject.customers_fullname AS subject_name
```

> By default, table aliases are case sensitive on Unix, but not so on Windows or Mac OSX.

Alias name is case sensitive in `UNIX` OS [Reference](http://chapter31.com/2008/08/22/mysql-alias-just-like-table-names-are-case-sensitive-on-nix/).